# How to download dropbox file using oauth

Tags: oauth

I am using `oauth` to authenticate dropbox and download a file from dropbox after getting access_token am using the below signature for download a file from dropbox am passing the root, path of the file, consumerKey and oauth_token with signature_method as PLAINTEXT and am getting an error

```
{"error": "Bad oauth_signature for oauth_signature_method 'PLAINTEXT'"}
```

Signature am using is given below :
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files?oauth_consumer_key=twcek2m7cxtantc&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_token=1jczc39y7rn1265&oauth_version=1.0&path=test%2Fut.txt&root=dropbox&oauth_signature=fbs34nykryouuj1%2526gbwmn3e27g97cfy

What should I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching about this and found that:

1) The PLAINTEXT method does not provide any security protection and SHOULD only be used over a secure channel such as HTTPS. It does not use the Signature Base String.

2) The Service Provider declares support for the HMAC-SHA1 signature method for all requests, and PLAINTEXT only for secure (HTTPS) requests.

3) When used with PLAINTEXT signatures, the OAuth protocol makes no attempts to protect User credentials from eavesdroppers or man-in-the-middle attacks. The PLAINTEXT signature algorithm is only intended to be used in conjunction with a transport-layer security mechanism such as TLS or SSL which does provide such protection. If transport-layer protection is unavailable, the PLAINTEXT signature method should not be used.

You can refer this link http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor22

You can also check if your keys are correct

The signature Protocol Parameters are set with the following values unencrypted:

oauth_signature_method : Set to PLAINTEXT.
oauth_signature : Set to the concatenated encoded value of the oauth_consumer_secret parameter and the value of the oauth_token_secret parameter. If the values contain a . character (ASCII code 46), it must be encoded as %2E. The values are separated by a . character (ASCII code 46), even if empty. The result MUST not be encoded again.
For example, if the Consumer Key is dj.9rj$0jd78jf88 and Token Secret is jjd999(j88ui.hs3, the encoded values are:

Consumer Key : dj%2E9rj%240jd78jf88
Token Secret : jjd999%28j88ui%2Ehs3
And the oauth_signature value is dj%2E9rj%240jd78jf88.jjd999%28j88ui%2Ehs3. This value is not encoded anymore and is used as it in the HTTP request. If the Token Secret is empty, the value is dj%2E9rj%240jd78jf88. (the separator . is retained).

Comment: can u send some sample url to download a file from dropbox using like above signature.